# Can't run UWP release executable outside of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: dll, uwp, visual-studio-2017, executable, release

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 with the official UWP sample code.

There is a UWP sample called **basicinput** that runs as a release build within the Visual Studio IDE without a problem.

**My problem is:**

when I attempt to run the release basicinput.exe executable by a mouse click (outside of the Visual Studio environment) I get an error saying that some DLLs names of the form `vs*.dll` can't be found.

I did a search for those `.dll`s and tried moving them to same folder as basicinput.exe, but then the application just hung.

What don't I understand?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running the executable from its install directory (as opposed to the build directory)?

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps). Visual Studio deploys the UWP appx package locally, which you can start without VS by finding the tile in your Start menu and clicking it. If you want to launch your UWP from the command line, you should use [protocol activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps)

Comment: I need to be able to determine the command line needed to build a c++ uwp application (like basicinput) and I need be determine the command line needed to execute the application.

Answer (score 5):

As @Chuck-walbourn says, your application will appear in the Start Menu. If you want to deploy it to another computer (that doesn't have VS installed) you will need to create AppX packages using the menu item `Project` -> `Store` -> `Create App Packages...`. If you need more help with that. see [the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps).

If you want to run your app from the command-line or from the `Win+R` dialog (with a simple name like `foo.exe`) you can create an [`appExecutionAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-appexecutionalias) for your application.

Comment: I need to be able to determine the command line needed to build a uwp application (like basicinput) and I need be determine the command line needed to execute the application.

Comment: Have you tried the protocol activation as @Chuck Walbourn 's comment? Or the `appExecutionAlias` in this answer?  details about `appExecutionAlias` see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/#VHqdFm1aIKP0EyYR.97

Comment: It is now under Project -> Publish